# The Rif and the Rosh on Nazir and Sotah

Tags: sources-mekorot, tractate-sotah, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi, rabbeinu-asher, maseches-nazir

Where can I find the commentaries of the Rif and of the Rosh on Tractates Nazir and Sotah? They're not in my gemara (Oz v'Hadar), and I was wondering if they were appended to a different tractate?

Comment: Are you sure they exist?

Comment: Do you mean the halachic compendia? (Or, e.g., _Tos'fos Harosh_?)

Comment: I've added an answer, but am still open to receiving more information about this if anybody knows anything that they would like to add. The compendium that I was referring to was Pisqei haRosh, which was compiled by his son. I don't know why it exists for Menachot (for example) and not for Nazir. I don't see how Menachot lends itself more to halakha lemaaseh than do those tractates that are missing this invaluable resource.

Comment: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?10213

Comment: Wow - thanks, @Michoel! I wonder why it wasn't included in the Oz v'Hadar version of the gemara, seeing as they saw fit to cram in just about everything else.

Answer (score 3):

To my surprise, it turns out that neither the Rif nor the Rosh ever penned commentaries to those two masekhtas. According to the Jewish Encyclopedia articles ("Alfasi, Isaac ben Jacob" and "Asher ben Jehiel", respectively), the Rif's Sefer haHalakhot covers only Berakhot, Shabbat, Eruvin, Pesachim, Ta'anit, Beitzah, Rosh haShana, Yoma, Sukkah, Megillah, Mo'ed Qatan, Yevamot, Ketubot, Gittin, Qiddushin, Nedarim, Chullin, Bava Qamma, Bava Metzia, Bava Batra, Sanhedrin, Makkot, Shevu'ot and Avodah Zarah ([link](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1191-alfasi-isaac-ben-jacob)).

The commentary of the Rosh covers only Seder Zeraim (except for Berakhot), tractates Nedarim and Tamid, and all of Seder Taharot. The digest of those commentaries that was composed by his son, titled "Pisqei haRosh", is appended to a range of other tractates as well (just taking a few randomly from the shelf, I found it on Bava Qama, Sanhedrin and Menachot), though is evidently not appended to all of them. The Jewish Encyclopedia article doesn't list which tractates it is found on and which it is not, though it appears then to be totally absent from Nazir and Sotah amongst others ([link](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12887-rosh)). How many others, I don't know.

Comment: Rosh (Rabeinu Asher) or Rash (R' Shimshon)?

Comment: Are you talking about the Tosfos Harosh? (I think that he wants the piskei harosh)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Rabbeinu Asher ben Yechiel. Why do you ask?

Comment: Which peirush are you referring to, the Piskei Harosh or the Tosfos Harosh?

Comment: Pisqei haRosh. I'm actually not familiar at all with Tosafot haRosh.

Comment: Ok, this is getting confusing. Here's what's going on: The Rosh wrote four things: (1) A commentary on parts of the Talmud. This is **not** what he is famous for; many people hardly know it exists. (2) A Talmudic Halchic "digest" (i.e. a summary of the halachic sections of the Talmud). This is what he is famous for, and it is appended to the back of virtually all *masechtos* in the Vilna Shas. Now the Piskei HaRosh is a point-by-point summary of the halachic "bottom-lines" that come out of this "digest" of the Rosh. That was written by his son, the Tur. [cont]

Comment: [cont] (3) Tosafos HaRosh, which is basically the Rosh's version of *tosafos* on many *masechtos*, and it is very similar to the "regular" *tosafos* on the side of the page in the Vilna Shas. (4) Responsa. </list> Please edit this answer (and the question too for that matter) to be clearer with exactly what works of the Rosh you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

As Shimon bM's already answered:

> The Rif's Sefer haHalakhot covers only Berakhot, Shabbat, Eruvin, Pesachim, Ta'anit, Beitzah, Rosh haShana, Yoma, Sukkah, Megillah, Mo'ed Qatan, Yevamot, Ketubot, Gittin, Qiddushin, Nedarim, Chullin, Bava Qamma, Bava Metzia, Bava Batra, Sanhedrin, Makkot, Shevu'ot and Avodah Zarah

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel), there is an opinion that the halachic compendium of the Rosh (his best known work) is a commentary on the Rif, rather than a commentary directly on the talmud. As such it seems to me that wouldn't exist on any masechta that the Rif didn't write about (Wikipedia cites the Shach, as quoted in Kelalei HaRif, Rabbeinu Asher VeTur printed before the Rosh on Shabbat, Klal 2). The existance of the Rosh on any masechta that the Rif didn't write about would disprove this opinion of the Shach. (There is a differing opinion that the Rosh wrote on the Talmud directly - Wikipedia cites the S'dei Chemed klallei haposkim s.v. Rosh.)

Since the Piskei HaRosh (compiled by his son) is a summary of the halachic conclusions in the aforementioned compendium, it wouldn't exist on any masechta where the Rosh didn't write (and by implication, any masechta where the Rif didn't write).

Comment: See for example the preface to the Rosh on Berachot by the Mechaber of the Maadanei Yom Tov, second to last paragraph here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37952&pgnum=142
 -- There he says that the Rosh is based on the Rif